# Word Addressable Memory

Tags: cpu-word, 32-bit, addressing

For a 32 bit word addressable memory, the word has size of 4 bytes.

If I try to store a data structure uses less than 4 byte memory, say 2 bytes. Is the remaining 2 bytes wasted?

Should we consider the word size when we decide what data structure to use?

Got similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622077/why-use-integers-smaller-than-32bit) but not exactly what i am asking.

Please help.

Comment: Your compiler would be free to implement a 16 bit store (`uint16_t x; ... x = 33; ...`) as: `ld x, %r0; and 0xffff0000, %r0; or 33, %r0; store %r0, x;`. So it could balance space / performance as it saw fit.

Comment: You ask about "word addressable memory" here, which is fine, it's an interesting subject with interesting implications, but byte addressable memory is more common. So, be careful to apply the implications of word addressable memory only to systems that actually have it.

Comment: Indeed.  Word-addressable memory means ... that individual bytes do not have their own address.  In that case, you're generally much better off not trying to use integers smaller than a word (unless you have a huge number of them).

Comment: It depends on the computer design.  I worked on a machine with 36 bit words so everything you did was read a word, use the part you needed, and then write back the resulting 36 bit word.  So a struct would take a multiple of 36 bytes but you could have as much data in each 36 bit word as you wanted.  The whole read-modify-write thing would be hidden from you by the language you used (unless it was assembly and then you had to do it yourself)

Comment: Of course. But extracting and inserting subword units took more CPU cycles (even if you had single instructions to do it) and the information to locate a subword unit was larger than a memory address - you typically need address of word, position in word, and size of subword unit.  Was this a DEC PDP-10 by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a modern CPU, memory itself is retrieved in usually chunks called *cache lines* (64 bytes on x86), but the CPU instruction set can address individual bytes.

If you had some esoteric machine with an instruction set that couldn't address individual bytes, then your compiler would hide that from you.

Whether or not memory is wasted in data structures smaller than a word would depend on the language you use and its implementation, but generally, records are aligned according to the field with the coarsest requirement.  If you have an array of 16 bit integers, they will pack together tightly.

Comment: so for a specific case, i declare a variable A and a variable B and each has size of 2 bytes. In 32 bit word addressable memory, can they be inserted on the same address? if yes, how it works in word addressable memory? If no, are total 4 bytes wasted?

Comment: Yes, the compiler can choose to use the top half of the word for one variable and the bottom half for the other, just like bit fields in C/C++.  Why do you think that each variable would require its own address?

Comment: this is probably my misconception. For example in here:https://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs1410/textbook/4.Pointers/vars_address.html, it mentions "The compiler has the task of mapping every variable name to its unique memory address". Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: That chapter is about pointers.  On a hypothetical machine with word-addressed memory, a pointer to something smaller than a word could not be implemented as a simple address.  A language that provides byte pointers would shift the address to the left and use a couple bits to indicate which byte inside the word was being pointed to.  This would make the generated machine code for accessing those bytes more complicated, unless the machine's instruction set included instructions to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 or 4 integers, it scarcely matters whether you store them in 2, 4, or 8 bytes.

If you have 3 or 4 billion integers, then it's probably worth considering a more space-efficient structure.

Generally speaking, the natural integer size for a given language implementation is supposed to be optimal in some way, so my advice is in general 'use int unless you know it's not appropriate' and let the compiler worry about it - until you have performance data to show otherwise.

Comment: So do you mean the space is always wasted if the data size is less than 4 byte?

Comment: (1)  It depends on your language, on your compiler, on your implementation, as to how much space is allocated in memory for an 8-bit number.  (2) It depends on what you mean by "wasted" - if using a 32-bit word for a 8-bit number uses fewer clock cycles, I don't call it wasted.